# How to track ListView, other views and urls via Mixins in Django App

Tags: python, django, analytics, mixins

Friends,

I have a Django app and I want to add some basic tracking for all my views. (Much like a counter or something similar)

What I have so far is that I can track specific objects with mixins. So every time someone is clicking on an instance of my model (the DetailView) an entry is added to my database. I did this via the django content types.

Now, to do this I need a get method to actually get a specific object back.

But in my ListView I don't have that object.

How could I implement something similar for either urls or just my ListView? Is that even possible? I'd like to record a single entry stating that the list of my model has been accessed.

Here is what I have so far:

my views

```
class ListJobView(ObjectViewMixin, ListView):
    model = Job
    context_object_name = 'jobs'
    template_name = 'list_jobs.html'
    ordering = '-pub_date'
    # paginate_by = 1

class DetailJobView(ObjectViewMixin, DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'detail_job.html'
    queryset = Job.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Job, id=id)
```

my mixin

```
from .signals import object_viewed_signal

class ObjectViewMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            instance = None

        if instance is not None:
            object_viewed_signal.send(instance.__class__, instance=instance, request=request)


        return super(ObjectViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

my signal

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

object_viewed_signal = Signal(providing_args=['instance', 'request'])
```

here is the signal handler:

```
    def object_viewed_receiver(sender, instance, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_viewed_object = ObjectViewed.objects.create(
            user         = request.user,
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender),
            object_id   = instance.id,
        )

    object_viewed_signal.connect(object_viewed_receiver)
```

If I should provide more code please let me know.

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: I suggest you post the signal handler and clarify whether you want to save one entry for each of the instances returned by your list, or you want to record a single entry stating that the list of some model has been accessed

Comment: Very good idea, thanks. I added the signal handler and clarification. Again here: I'd like to increment a counter when the ListView is being accessed. Or in your words: I'd like to record a single entry stating that the list of some model has been accessed.

Comment: ... no one has an idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Vasco. Yes, I built something to track all my URLs. So I can track a link everytime someone visits it. If it helps you  I can post how I did it here on the weekend? I did it with a middle ware.

Comment: Dear Micromegas .. can you please your solution

Comment: @MohamedAbbase I posted my solution the best I could remember. I hope it helps you. All the best

Answer (score 1):

So this answer is without any guarantees to work. I implemented this solution at the time I was asking the question but I am not using it anymore since I removed this functionality from my django app. A reason for this was the heavy load. Because in this solution I create an object for every time someone visits the website and save it to the DB. This works fine but gets really heavy for the DB after a while.

First I created and new app and called it `analytics`. In the app I created model like this:

```
class UrlTime(models.Model):
    associated_url = models.CharField(blank=True, null= True, max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.associated_url
```

I created a new module called `middleware.py`. A middleware basically executes code either before a view is called or after a view is called (dependent where you put the code). If you count URLs I think it's good to have it before a view is called:

middleware.py

```
from .models import UrlTime

class GetUrlMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # before view
        # creates a counter object for URL if url doesn't exist. Else counts up.
        if request.path.startswith('/admin/'):  ##exclude what you don't want to count
            pass
        else:
            # urltrack, _ = UrlTrack.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            # urltrack.counter = F('counter') + 1
            # urltrack.save()

            urltime = UrlTime.objects.create(associated_url=request.path)
            urltime.save()

        response = self.get_response(request)
        # after view

        return response
```

With this you should be able to count your URls every time someone visits the page. An object will be created in the DB. Then you only have to display it how you want it on a template. I did something like this:

```
class AnalyticsIndexView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'analytics_list.html'
    model = UrlTime

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AnalyticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_viewed_list'] = ObjectViewed.objects.all()
        context['url_views_list'] = UrlTime.objects.all()
        context['total_views'] = UrlTime.objects.all().count
        counting = UrlTime.objects.all().values('associated_url').annotate(url_count=Count('associated_url'))
        context['home_view'] = counting
        context['start'] = UrlTime.objects.first()

        return context
```

Then you just need to implement the template.... If you need that too let me know and I post it here too.